# Load MySQL dump in Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku

I have a sql dump from my previous MySQL server, how do I load this file in Heroku?. Would I have to change to Postgres?. And then upload dump file to S3 as said [here](http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2012/09/heroku-importrestore-data-database-postgres-dump-file/).

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a great [guide on how to migrate a MySQL database to PostgreSQL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql#migrate-to-heroku-postgres). Alternatively, you can provision one of the MySQL-compatible [add-ons](https://addons.heroku.com/) and use that.